# Initialize values of dynamic array in a function (C language)

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

this is my code:

```
void init_array(int** array) {

  *array = (int*) malloc(3 * sizeof(int));

  /* ???? **(array+2) = 666; */

  return;
}

void init(int* array, int* length) {

  *length = 3;

  *(array+0) = 0;
  *(array+1) = 1;
  *(array+2) = 2;

  return;

}

int main(void) {

  /* Variables */

  int array_length;
  int* array;

  /* Initialize */

  init_array(&array);
  init(array, &array_length);

  free(array);

  return 0;

}
```

My question is: How can I initialize values of the array in a function init_array().

I have attempted things such as:

- `**(array+2) = 666;`
- `*(*(array+2)) = 666;`
- `*array[2] = 666;`
- `**array[2] = 666;`

When I used pencil and paper I came to result that `**(array+2)` should work but it gives me a segmentation fault.

I would appreciate your answer because I am confused how pointers in C actually work.

Comment: try `(*array)[2] = 666;` and compile with all warnings on.

Comment: I'm familiar with C++ but I thing you need to use the `new` operator or what ever to declare an object and then create the values in the specified address.

Comment: there's no new in C.

Comment: Oh alright Jean, wasn't sure!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the address of a pointer passed to the function:

```
array
```

You want to dereference that to get the pointer:

```
*array
```

Then apply the array subscript operator to the result:

```
(*array)[2]
```

Or equivalently:

```
*((*array) + 2)
```

The parenthesis are required because the array subscript operator `[]` has higher precedence than the dereference operator `*`.

Generally speaking, you should use the array subscript operator whenever possible, as it tends to be easier to read.